# Source control firebase's remote config

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config

Is there anyway to source control firebase's remote config values? It would be very troublesome if the values were changed without a way to trace back to which user changed it and more importantly, a convenient way to roll back to its previous state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At present there is no way to do so but we are aware of this issue and have it on our list.  Will post here when there is a feature that helps.